# Child span tag with Jquery and HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to call from Jquery the `text` field inside the HTML.
I have tried many scenarios without any luck. This is the last try.
I have also searched through Jquery site, but I could find property/method which could do this.

```js
$('.cjmp-drag-element-content').on("click", function(event){
    var title = $(".cjmp-drag-element-content span:last").text(event.target.tagName);
   $(title).substring(0, 10);
    });
```

```html
<div class="cjmp-drag-element-content cjmp-optional cjmp-choosen">
<span class="cjm-score-value" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">0.0</span>
<span class="cjmp-content-visitors" id="cjmpc-visitors-181">100%</span>
<span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 220%; width: 135px; padding: 2px 4px; height:27px;">cjasdgasga 1</span>
</div>
```

Ultimately I am trying to cut the HTML tag (cjasdgasga 1) to just (cjasd) and to bring three dots at the end of the line. So something like this. (cjasd...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need must of the code you wrote, and calling `.substring()` on a `jQuery` object - which is being selected wrongly anyway - won't do what you're expecting.

This should solve your problem:

```
$(function() {
  $('.cjmp-drag-element-content').on('click', function() {
    var el = $(this).find("span:last");
    el.text(el.text().substring(0, 10));
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nwuehko6/)

Comment: Thanks MelanciaUK, this also solves my issue in another way. I wasn't forming my question correctly. Anyhow then it solves the issue all over my page which is not behavior that I want. I want this to happen only for the element which was clicked on. Not everywhere else.

Comment: The `$(this)` object within the `click` handler makes sure the code is executed against just the clicked element, not all of them - the ones with the same class.

Comment: Sorry again, I am using the same class all over the place. I have to have an specific identifier right ? Could I add a class every time I click ?

Comment: In the code above you'll be attaching the event handler to all elements that have that class. When any of them receives a click, within the handler you know which one by referring to `$(this)`. If you want to handle the click on a single element, then yes, you'll need to give it an specific identifier and use it instead of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This works: *you can't call substring on a jquery object since its a javascript function*

```js
$('.cjmp-drag-element-content').on("click", function(){
    // get the text from the last child span
    var title = $(".cjmp-drag-element-content span:last-child").text();
    // get a substring of the text
    var newTitle = title.substring(0, 5);
    // replace the current text with the substring and add the dots
    $(".cjmp-drag-element-content span:last-child").text(newTitle + "...");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cjmp-drag-element-content cjmp-optional cjmp-choosen">
<span class="cjm-score-value" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">0.0</span>
<span class="cjmp-content-visitors" id="cjmpc-visitors-181">100%</span>
<span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 220%; width: 135px; padding: 2px 4px; height:27px;">cjasdgasga 1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dex Dave, but isn't Javascript and Jquery event based ?
Why do I ask this ? I have on my page multiple occurrences of HTML tags with divs and spans, in other words, I don't want this event to happen everywhere on my page. I just want to select one. This isn't possible or I have to id to every div ? Or how should I solve this ?

Comment: you are welcome and you could use an ID on the span/div that you need then it would be unique because no other ID would be the same